# Verifying that the no arg version of an overloaded function gets called in scalamock

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, scalamock

I am using scalamock and am trying to verify that the `close()` method in the RabbitMQ `com.rabbitmq.client.Channel` class is getting called. The problem is the `close()` method is overloaded with two options: `close()` and `close(int, String)`. I want to verify that the no arg version is getting called.

I have tried the following code:

```
import com.rabbit.client.Channel
import org.scalatest.Wordspec
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class MessageSubscriberSpecs extends WordSpec with MockFactory {
  "A message subscriber" when {
    "closing a connection" should {
      // ... More test setup

      "close the underlying connection" in {
        val channelStub = stub[Channel]
        (channelStub.close _).verify()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The line with `verify()` on it does not compile because the compiler is confused about which overloaded function to call.

**How do I verify that the no arg version of an overloaded function gets called?**

Answer (score 1):

You can add an explicit type annotation for the function. In this case it's a no args method with a void return type, so it would be:

```
(channelStub.close _: () => Unit).verify()
```

likewise to match the other overloaded signature, it would be

```
(channelStub.close _: (Int,String) => Unit).verify(*,*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's confused of which function it should create: `Function0` or `Function2` (i.e. a function with 0 or 2 parameters)

So let's solve this by explicitly defining a function with 0 parameters!

```
(() => channelStub.close()).verify()
```